# Make a reverse dynamic port forward using only Plink

Tags: ssh, tunnel, socks, plink

A lot of tuto online give an explanation about how to configure ssh to make a dynamic port forwarding server. In my case, **using only Plink**, I have some trouble.

The context is as follow : I want all my trafic (HTTP, RDP, etc.) from my `HOSTA` (Linux machine)to be redirected to `HOSTB` (Windows machine).

My commands are as follow:

**[HOSTB - Windows machine]**

```
plink.exe -N -D 127.0.0.1:8888 -P 22 REMOTEIP
plink.exe -N -R 2222:127.0.0.1:8888 -P 22 REMOTEIP
```

**[HOSTA - Linux machine]**

```
 curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:2222 https://www.google.com
```

All ports are well opened (8888 on HOSTB and 2222 on HOSTA). However, It seems that trafic will go out from HOSTA, but not from HOSTB.
I tried with different programs and different socks versions, still the same problem

Am I missing something?

Thanks !

Comment: not sure if it can be the case, but [`plink`](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter7.html) seems to have swapped the `-R` and `-L` switches from the meaning of the OpenSSH. If that is so, you should use `-L` instead of `-R`. I hope the semantics is not different either.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I heard something about it long time ago, but after testing, it seems that it does not work too. Do you have an other idea?

Comment: This behavior is expected. By creating the first tunnel (`-D 127.0.0.1:8888`), you're saying "all traffic that enters port 8888 will be proxied through the _remote_ host [through a socks proxy]" (which is what `-D` is for). Thus, by accepting traffic on HOSTA and forwarding it through that local port 8888 on HOSTB, you are effectively rerouting it all again through HOSTA. To fix the situation, `plink.exe` would need to ssh to localhost (rather than REMOTEIP) to make a 'local dynamic socks proxy', but that would require to run sshd on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but it keeps coming up.

As mentioned in the comments to your question, your attempts result in a dynamic port forward to the system you wish to initiate the communications from (the SOCKS client). And that won't accomplish the reverse dynamic port forwarding you were hoping for.

What you would need is the following:

```
plink.exe -N -R 2222:127.0.0.1:8888 -P 22 REMOTEIP
and
  # when local host is running SSH Server
  plink.exe -N -D 127.0.0.1:8888 -P 22 localhost
or
  # when local host has not SSH Server
  plink.exe -N -D 8888 -P 22 PROXYSSHIP
or
  # when a dedicated SOCKS proxy server is available
  plink.exe -N -L 8888:SOCKSPROXYIP:SOCKPORT
```

You can replace `localhost` with another SSH server that can do Dynamic Port Forwarding or you can forward traffic to a SOCKS proxy server.  But, to accomplish your goal, which ever server you choose must be on the network you want to proxy.

So, a problem often arises when you don't have an SSH Server on the targeted network that you can connect to.  For example, `localhost` does not have an SSHd (server) running and you don't have an account on another SSH enabled server on that network.  Furthermore, if you don't know of any SOCKS proxy's serving that network, your options are greatly reduced.

Without an SSHd to connect to, you can't do it because PLINK (0.63) is a client that does not have a SOCKS implementation.  If you were using [OpenSSH 7.6 or later](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.6), the SSH client does have the SOCKS feature, meaning you could connect back to your client box with the command...

```
ssh me@mine -R 1080 -N -f
```

... and the SSH client would act as the proxy server (no need for a separate proxy server).  Alas, this is only available in tools that are build with OpenSSH 7.6+, AFAIK.

So, things you could try are below.  1, 2, and 3 work with the changes outlined above, while 4 and 5 require research.

1. You could install an SSH server on your windows client and use `localhost` above
2. You could identify another server on the same network as your windows client that you can connect to with PLINK and run your SOCKS proxy there.
3. You could identify an existing socks proxy that is already doing what you want.
4. You could try to find a later version of PLINK hoping that the SOCKS feature has been added to it like it has in OpenSSH 7.6+
5. You might be able to use "Secure Socket Funneling", but it requires setting up a server somewhere that both your socks client and your windows client can reach, and it requires running the SSF client on your windows client.  I haven't yet done this myself so I am not speaking from experience.

Comment: "Alas, this is only available on Linux." - do you have some source on this? I've been trying to make reverse socks work on windows (both server and client use built-in ssh in windows 10), but I'm getting "Connection reset by [ip] port [port]" as soon as remote host tries to use created proxy. So on client I do "ssh -R 1080 server_ip". Then on server I configure system proxy with address localhost:1080. As soon as I try to access e.g. any website above error happens.

Comment: I just added a link to the OpenSSH 7.6 release notes where under the changes since 7.5, they list the new behavior of -R.  As for "only available on Linux", I will change that phrase as well to say "only available in tools build with OpenSSH 7.6+"